Confusion about stability of PDEs.
I have been reading about Stability Theory and have been left with some questions at is seems to me that some of its notions are not very well-defined or at least inconsistently used.

Consider the case of a nonlinear PDE...
Smallness of perturbations: When one wants to investigate the behaviour of "small" perturbations -- how is "small" defined, i.e. at what point is a perturbation not considered small anymore? In order to ascertain stability, one looks at the linearisation of the PDE. Does the notion of "smallness" arise from this linearisation, as the linearisation is a good approximation for "near enough" solutions only?
Nonlinear stability: Is a nonlinear PDE considered stable if its linearisation is stable or is there something as linearly-stable and nonlinearly stable, where the PDE is only called stable if it is both linearly-stable and nonlinearly stable. The literature seems to be a bit inconsistent here.
Blow-up behaviour: If a nonlinear PDE is already considered stable if its linearisation is stable, then am I correct in assuming that a stable PDE may after all exhibit blowup behaviour as long as the initial conditions are "far from" an equilibrium? How would one characterise (or call) the ability or inability to exhibit blow-up behaviour? Is there a name for it that I can up and look into?

This note set and the included references should answer most of your questions: https://depts.washington.edu/bdecon/workshop2012/g_stability.pdf
